# Debugging Django on Docker on Vagrant with IDE

Tags: django, docker, vagrant, python-3.4

I have quite the Docker stack at the moment, compiled from many containers, one of which is running an instance of Django.

At the moment, I'm limited to debugging by importing `logging` and using

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("your variable: " + variableName)
```

It's totally inefficient and requires me to rebuild the docker stack every time I want to re-evaluate a change.

I'm used to working in Komodo and having a robust, step-able debugger at my disposal, but I can's seem to find any documents on how to wire up a Docker container inside a vagrant VM to an IDE (or command line debugger) that will let me step through code without a rebuild.

How can I wire up a debugging IDE to a docker container inside a Vagrant VM? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used docker but as far as I know it's just a "chroot" system. You can just run your python code in debug mode and remote connect to it with debbuger

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Docker Compose to handle and link your containers. I'm also using a Docker stack on my dev env with a container for
 - django
 - postgres
 - nginx

You just have to synchronize your code with the code inside your docker container. To do that, use the **volumes** command in your docker-compose file. Here is an example, with 2 containers (django and postgres) :

```js
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/webapp
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

**This portion of code will do what you want.** All your project `.` will be synchronized with the `/webapp` folder of your docker container then, no more need to rebuild your docker image:

```
volumes:
    - .:/webapp
```

Then, to debug, I recommend you to use **pdb**, which is in my opinion , the best way to debug your django app, run :

```
docker-compose -f [path/to/your/docker-compose.yml] --service-ports  [name-of-your-django-container] python manage.py runserver
```

E.g :

```
docker-compose -f django_project/docker-compose.yml --service-ports django python manage.py runserver
```

Let's debug a view :
1. import pdb in the view :`import pdb`
2. add `pdb.set_trace()` in a method or a class in your view
3. request the right url
and you will be able to debug through your terminal
You should have something like that :

```python
(Pdb) > /webapp/car/views.py(18)get()
-> for car in serializer.data:
```

Here is a tutorial to use Compose and Django from Docker : [Quickstart Guide: Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)

Comment: This is what I'm doing. The question is how to develop from a step-able IDE for stepping through code to debug / test.

Comment: I have update my answer. This is how I debug my Django project with pdb in a docker container. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15 and since the code is not executed on your machine,  I think you can't use for example breakpoint feature of your IDE.

Comment: And I think, this is not what you are doing because I'm doing that and I don't need to rebuild my containers. I can test/debug in real-time through the terminal of my IDE

Comment: I don't see any mention of Vagrant in your setup - that's why I suggest you're doing it w/o Vagrant as the host for Docker.